# QBXML Receive payment applied to multiple Invoices

Tags: qbxml

I'm trying to apply 1 payment to multiple invoices with QBXML and I'm getting the following error

`QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream`

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
<ReceivePaymentAddRq>
<ReceivePaymentAdd>
    <CustomerRef>
        <ListID>8000254C-1444676392</ListID>
    </CustomerRef>
    <TxnDate>2018-12-13</TxnDate>
    <RefNumber>457</RefNumber>
    <TotalAmount>863.10</TotalAmount>
    <Memo></Memo>
    <PaymentMethodRef><FullName/></PaymentMethodRef>
    <AppliedToTxnAdd>
       <TxnID>11B0C6-1544760951</TxnID>
       <PaymentAmount>179.00</PaymentAmount>
    </AppliedToTxnAdd>
    <AppliedToTxnAdd>
       <TxnID>11B0CA-1544761043</TxnID>
       <PaymentAmount>684.10</PaymentAmount>
    </AppliedToTxnAdd>
</ReceivePaymentAdd><IncludeRetElement>TxnID</IncludeRetElement><IncludeRetElement>RefNumber</IncludeRetElement></ReceivePaymentAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

Notice I have 2 `AppliedToTxnAdd` elements.

However if I only apply 1 `AppliedToTxnAdd`, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the order of the xml elements. QB cares about that.